# Toast notification navigate WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Looking for information, but I failed to find. Tell me, how do I make the navigation to the desired page when clicking on a normal notification.
Interested in how to do it while closed and open app.

p.s. I mean ScheduledToastNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using UWP, you need to handle activation in your `protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)` method in App.xaml.cs. If `args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification` then `args` is of type `ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs`.

See:

- [Quickstart: Sending a local toast notification and handling activations from it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/)
- [Adaptive and interactive toast notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts)

Comment: I OnLaunched is triggered when an open application, when I click on the notification

Comment: OnActivated does not work. When closed, the application is likely OnActivated work, however I need to handle and when you open the app.

Comment: @АлександрАнаньев Please read the whole article, it contains several forms of activations from toasts, some of them have to work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I found the answer to your question thanks to the answer above. From the above article I went to https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to your question due to @Squidward.
From the above article I went to https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868212.aspx

In my code I added the following and my OnLanched field in the Arguments data. Now I might be able to make plans!

```
        ToastTemplateType _toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
        XmlDocument _toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(_toastTemplate);

        //this set argument for OnLaunched
        IXmlNode toastNode = _toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "111111");
        //---
```